# Rugged/tough smartphones that support LineageOS?

Tags: smartphones

Do you guy know tough smartphones for industrial and construction workers that support LineageOS?
Something like:

https://blog.puls.com/most-durable-phones

- LineageOS 16 or 17 support.
- Durable and waterproof would be nice.
- 5.5in screen or more.

Comment: Frame challenge: Ruggedized case for a proper phone.

Phones with LineageOS support are usually popular and reaonably specced / valued. There's no rugged / though smartphone that's reasonably valued, so they just tend to not be popular either.